# Change the background color of the icon in taskbar in adobe air

Tags: javascript, windows, air

Is it possible to change the background color of the icon in taskbar on windows? I'm going to build a simple chat application using adobe air with html/javascript and want to use this feature as a notification for new incoming messages, like in facebook messenger app, for example (see image).

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do several thing to notify the user via the `NativeApplication`,`SystemTrayIcon` and `DockIcon` classes.

On windows you can flash the application icon on the task bar and in OSX you can make the icon bounce to notify the user of a change / action required.

A summary of the methods used can be found on Adobe's site under [Working with the dock and the system tray](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/flash/quickstart/articles/stopwatch_dock_system_tray.html)

Although these examples are in as3, they are relatively similar to the js classes which can be found in the AIR HTML API Reference

[NativeApplication](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/air/reference/html/flash/desktop/NativeApplication.html)

[SystemTrayIcon](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/air/reference/html/flash/desktop/SystemTrayIcon.html)

[DockIcon](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/air/reference/html/flash/desktop/DockIcon.html)